# How to have urls with a '$' in a SASS file?

Tags: sass

I've inherited legacy code, and theres this portion of a class in css:

```
background: url(//site.com/path/path/$?wid=3&fmt=png/myimg.jpg)
```

SASS throws an error because it things the '$' is a variable. How can I get around this if I cannot modify the image path on the server?

Comment: you can use quotes: `background: url("//site.com/path/path/$?wid=3&fmt=png/myimg.jpg") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the URL in quotes.  Sass does not look for variables within quoted strings, instead you would have to use the interpolation syntax `#{}`

```
background: url('//site.com/path/path/$?wid=3&fmt=png/myimg.jpg')
```